# convert wmf to jpg with graphicsmagick, unable to read font

Tags: imagemagick, graphicsmagick, wmf

I try to convert a wmf file into a jpg. gm says it is "Unable to read font (n021004l.pfb) [No such file or directory]." My command is like that:
gm convert 456.wmf 456.jpg

What could be wrong? I am using the latest gm version 1.3.29 and have ghostscript installed. OS: Windows 7

Here's the small file that I am trying to convert: https://mycloud.m-box.at/index.php/s/lBMeCG0cjK45sI1

And here's the version log (wmf is enabled):

```
GraphicsMagick 1.3.29 2018-04-29 Q16 http://www.GraphicsMagick.org/
Copyright (C) 2002-2018 GraphicsMagick Group.
Additional copyrights and licenses apply to this software.
See http://www.GraphicsMagick.org/www/Copyright.html for details.

Feature Support:
  Native Thread Safe       yes
  Large Files (> 32 bit)   yes
  Large Memory (> 32 bit)  yes
  BZIP                     yes
  DPS                      no
  FlashPix                 no
  FreeType                 yes
  Ghostscript (Library)    no
  JBIG                     yes
  JPEG-2000                yes
  JPEG                     yes
  Little CMS               yes
  Loadable Modules         yes
  OpenMP                   yes (200203)
  PNG                      yes
  TIFF                     yes
  TRIO                     no
  UMEM                     no
  WebP                     yes
  WMF                      yes
  X11                      no
  XML                      yes
  ZLIB                     yes

Windows Build Parameters:

  MSVC Version:            1500
```

Comment: Please click `edit` under your question and paste in the result of `gm identify -version`

Comment: Thanks, Mark, for your comment. Debugging output didn't show any information that looked relevant for that issue. And as you ended your post with 'Sorry I can't help further' I took this as just that. Still, I'm grateful for your hint and suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This looks a bit odd. I would suggest you enable debugging messages and see if you can trace what is going wrong yourself.

So, use:

```
gm convert -debug all 456.wmf 456.jpg > debug.txt 2>&1
```

and then look at the last few lines in `debug.txt`.

Sorry I can't help further!